# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой Invalid response http code: 400 при oauth авторизации на instagram

Tags: yii, oauth, instagram

Использую oauth авторизацию для yii. Скачал extension по ссылке https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth. Написал класс для авторизации через instagram, в итоге получаю ошибку  Invalid response http code: 400

Answer (score 1):

400 Bad Request («плохой, негодный запрос»).
Скорей всего вы что-то не так отправляете. Покажите пример кода, а лучше сразу лог curl`a на запрос/ответ.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // error with open_basedir or safe mode
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);

Comment: Я имел ввиду код формирования запроса в инстаграмм. Используйте форматирование.